# How to check if a UIButtons title is equal to a specific string?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, boolean

I am trying to have a button that you can click and it will do x if the title is that string, other wise no.

```
if button.setTitle("Message", for: .normal) == true {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`currentTitle` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624032-currenttitle) to check the value you want.

The `setTitle` method should be used to set/update the title value, not get it.